# Passing data from a Swift Controller to an Objective-C controller

Tags: objective-c, swift, string, viewcontroller

I'm trying to pass a simple string from a Swift Controller to an Objective-C controller, but unfortunately it doesn't work.

**Error I get:**

> Value of type 'EUIDViewController' has no member 'stringPassed'

**Swift Code sending string**

```
let pvc = EUIDViewController(nibName: "ScannerViewController", bundle: nil)
if isHasCameraPermission {
    pvc.stringPassed = "test"
    present(pvc, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}
```

**Objective-C code receiving the string**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* stringPassed;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initOCR];
    NSLog(@"String: %@", self.stringPassed);
}
```

Update: I did #import "EUIDViewController.h" into the bridging-header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to declare `stringPassed` property in `.h` means header file of that `ViewController`.

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString* stringPassed;

@end
```

Comment: Oh thanks! I feel stupid... will mark your answer as the right one when I may!

Comment: @Isabelle  Welcome mate :)